# Table already exist

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using doctrine 2 in zend framework 2. Below is my entity file. The problem is, when I tried to validate schema using,

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
```

command.

I am getting error,

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                               
The table with name 'database.opportunitycriteria' already exists.
```

What should I do?

```
namespace Administration\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * OpportunityCriteria
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="OpportunityCriteria")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Criteria
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="criteria_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $criteria_id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $description;
}
```

and appropriate getter and setter methods..

Comment: Is there a class An entity class named  OpportunityCriteria?

Comment: From the looks this simply means that within some of your entity classes this line is repeated more then 1 time   @ORM\Table(name="OpportunityCriteria")
now this type of mistake usually happens when we Code by Copy/Paste

Comment: I'm getting this error and doing a search of the entity directory for @ORM\Table only shows one occurrence for the name of the table in question. (This type of mistake usually happens when you assume things.)

Comment: Could please you provide `composer.json` so I can repliace the issue?

Comment: Ping @Benjamin, could you provide your usecase data please?

Comment: @TomášVotruba I finally figured it out, check my answer below!

Answer (score 17):

I finally figured it out. OP's use case may be different, but in my case, this was because of a misconfigured bidirectional many-to-many relationship.

I had the following entities:

```php
class Cuisine {
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Dish")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="CuisineDish", ...)
     */
    protected $dishes;
}

class Dish {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Cuisine")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="CuisineDish", ...)
     */
    protected $cuisines;
}
```

What was missing was the `inversedBy` and `mappedBy` properties of the `@ManyToMany` annotations. These are only required when the association is bi-directional.

So now the correctly mapped entities look like:

```php
class Cuisine {
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Dish", inversedBy="cuisines")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="CuisineDish", )
     */
    protected $dishes;
}

class Dish {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Cuisine", mappedBy="dishes")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="CuisineDish", ...)
     */
    protected $cuisines;
}
```

And `orm:validate-schema` does not exit with an exception any more.

The exception message is just misleading, as the database is not altered by this operation. Furthermore, this issue is only spotted when validating the sync with the database, not when validating the mapping only (`--skip-sync`), where it should.

I just [reported this bug](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4824).

Answer (score 1):

it can cause this error message if you want to use a table name which is already used by one of the installed bundles.